# Unable to pull data even after successful login

Tags: .net, rets

I am uisng libRETS client library to pull data from a RETS server. Sample application provided with libRETS is not working for me. Login to RETS Server is succcessful and it returns following response to me.`<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<RETS ReplyText="Operation Successful" ReplyCode="0">
  <RETS-RESPONSE> MemberName=INTERNAL RETS User=***** Broker=***** MetadataVersion=1.00.00025 
  MetadataTimestamp=2012-05-30T21:36:03 MinMetadataTimestamp=2012-05-30T21:36:03 TimeoutSeconds=1800000 
  Login=/rets/login Logout=/rets/logout X-Selector=/rets/logselector </RETS-RESPONSE>
</RETS>` 
But when I try to search any thing i received following error

```
Invalid operation: null URL. Check login capability URL list.
```

I checked the capability list and it give empty string  for search url. Am I missing something or the RETS server does not allow searching through my account as it is clear from the login response where search url node is missing.

thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally,tech guys on MLS confirmed that my client's account does not have privileges to search data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consult the RETS specification here: http://rets.org/documentation.

The two commands you'll mostly likely use are Search (for property data) and GetObject (for pictures)

An example query to get property data for all residential homes with a listing status of active: (Your RETS server will have different field names than these)

query = (LIST_STATUS=ACT)
PropertyClass = RES

{RETS Server URL} + /Search.asmx/Search?SearchType=Property&Class= + {PropertyClass} + &QueryType=DMQL2&Query= + {query} + &Format=COMPACT-DECODED&Limit=50

Comment: Thanx for the reply but problem is not the query format or url format. What I want is to confirm that according to the login response i posted, My RETS Server does not allow me to search data.